# running AWS Windows server instance with amazon workspaces

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Its for a project and not for production and just verity and test windows server 2012 r2

i want to create a AWS server running with windows 2012 R2 with active directory and create a AWS workspace windows 7.

My question is, can i have them all on the same subnet within AWS vpc so the client (work space machine ) can be authenticated by the server, enforced group policy and do drive mapping ?

Comment: 1) They don't need to be on the same subnet for this to happen. Just put them in the same VPC and ensure that correct routes and Security Group rules are present. 2) Try it and find out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.  I was able to place my Amazon Workspace in the same VPC and subnet as my EC2 instance.  I did this by creating an AWS directory and assigning the directory to the same VPC and subnet as my existing EC2 instances.  When creating the AWS workspace I made sure to assign the workspace to this pre-configured directory.

You can also establish separate security profiles for the AWS instance thus allowing RDP connections (useful if you're using ubuntu as your client machine).  See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-workspace-rdp/ for more info